# NullInjectorError when using AngularFireAuthGuard

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angularfire

I am encountering a `NullInjectorError` while trying to leverage the `AngularFireAuthGuard` as explained in the [angularfire documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md).

Despite adding `AngularFireAuthGuard` and `AngularFireAuthGuardModule` to **app.module.ts**, it complains there isn't a provider for `Router`, even though I am importing `RouterModule` as well!

```
errors.ts:30 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireAuthGuard -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AngularFireAuthGuard -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireAuthGuard -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AngularFireAuthGuard -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
```

This is can be replicated in a [StackBlitz Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scftvu).

Answer (score 3):

When using @angular/fire version 7 or above you have to use AuthGuard, see below!

```
import { AuthGuard } from "@angular/fire/auth-guard";

canActivate: [AuthGuard],
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answer given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Answer (score 0):

NullInjectors errors occurs because missing Modules or Providers, try to add AngularFireAuthGuardModule on Modules export and Providers.

By example

```js
import { AngularFireAuthGuard } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  providers:    [ AngularFireAuthGuard ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  exports:      [ AppComponent, AngularFireAuthGuardModule ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Interesting about adding it to the exports for the AppModule... I’ll have to try that tonight when I am back in front of the computer. 

Out of curiosity- why would you need to export this? Also, you can replicate this in the StackBlitz link above.

Comment: That didn’t seem to work. :( I still have the same issue on StackBlitz.

Comment: I have the same problem with AngularFireAnalytics

Comment: it doesn't solve the issue, it's still same 


core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireAuthGuard]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AngularFireAuthGuard]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireAuthGuard!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireAuthGuard]: